# Как удалить элемент "a", через чистый javascript, зная класс?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="start"> 
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
</div>
```

Как мне удалить последний элемент или скрыть его?

Comment: `document.querySelector(“.class”).remove()`

Comment: это через jQuery?

Comment: нет, это нативный js

Comment: т.е. я должен вставить эту строчку после верстки и оно удалит при запуске?
<script>document.querySelector(“.start”).remove()</script>

Comment: ну да, вроде того

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, вот он прямо с такими кавычками и вставит)))

Comment: окей, я понял, он удаляет полностью весь класс, но мне нужно оставить div  внутри класса), убрать именно "a"

Comment: document.querySelector('.class a').remove()

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Cпасибо!!! :))

Answer (score 2):

Удаление элемента `<a>` из блока с классом `.start` (если таких элементов окажется несколько, то будет удалён первый найденный) :

```js
document.querySelector(`.start > a`).remove();
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
</div>
```

Скрытие последнего элемента (независимо от тега) в блоке с классом `.start`:

```js
document.querySelector(`.start > *:last-child`).style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
</div>
```

Скрытие *последнего* найденного элемента `<a>` в блоке с классом `.start`:

```js
document.querySelector(`.start > a:last-of-type`).style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
  <div>ещё текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то ещё</a>
  <div>снова текст</div>
</div>
```

Удаление *всех* элементов `<a>` из блока с классом `.start`:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(`.start > a`)].forEach(el => el.remove());
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
  <div>ещё текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то ещё</a>
  <div>снова текст</div>
</div>
```